# "NameError: name 'a' is not defined" in "finally" block

Tags: python, exception, file-handling

i am learning python but getting some error.

Here is my code:

```
try:
    a=open("doesnotexist.txt")
    content=a.read()
    print(content)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    a.close()
```

Here is result:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'doesnotexist.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/python learning/exhandling1.py", line 8, in <module> 
    a.close()
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: If `open("doesnotexist.txt")` throws an exception then `a` is never assigned a value. Use a `with` block instead.

Comment: The line `a=open("doesnotexist.txt")` raised an exception, therefore `a` was not assigned.  Code in the `finally` block should not depend on the `try` block being successful.

Comment: If the file does not exist (the exception is raised), then the name `a` will never be defined.

Comment: Would [`with`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) be helpful?

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 1):

`finally` is executed whether or not the `try`-block raises an exception. When `open()` raises a `FileNotFoundError`, `a` is not defined. You want to use `else` instead, which is executed if the `try`-block does not raise an exception.

However, using a [`with`-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is simpler, and it's best practice anyway:

```
try:
    with open("doesnotexist.txt") as a:
        content = a.read()
    print(content)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(e)
```

Sources:

- [Errors and Exceptions - Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)
- [The `try` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `open()` function threw an exception, the variable `a` didn't get assigned a value. Then, in the `finally` block, you tried to call a method of `a`, which isn't possible since `a` is not defined.

In general, when opening files, you should use a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

For example:

```py
try:
    with open('doesnotexist.txt', 'r') as opened_file:
        content = opened_file.read()
        print(content)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('no file found')
```